# "Failed to start controller in realtime loop" with UR/URe robot driver

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to start up a UR5 on ROS Melodic/Ubuntu 18.04 with [the ur_robot_driver package](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver), but I am getting the error  `Failed to start controller in realtime loop. This should never happen.` The full error log is below:

```
roslaunch ur_robot_driver ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.42 reverse_port:=50003 script_sender_port:=50004

... logging to /root/.ros/log/9ed9ba2e-7187-11ea-8a14-c8d3ff4172f5/roslaunch-o2ac-ur-27505.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
started roslaunch server http://localhost:44335/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /controller_stopper/consistent_controllers: ['joint_state_con...
 * /force_torque_sensor_controller/publish_rate: 125
 * /force_torque_sensor_controller/type: force_torque_sens...
 * /hardware_control_loop/loop_hz: 125
 * /hardware_interface/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
 * /joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 125
 * /joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /pos_traj_controller/action_monitor_rate: 10
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/goal_time: 0.6
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /pos_traj_controller/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
 * /pos_traj_controller/state_publish_rate: 125
 * /pos_traj_controller/stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
 * /pos_traj_controller/type: position_controll...
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.3
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/action_monitor_rate: 10
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/goal_time: 0.6
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/state_publish_rate: 125
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
 * /scaled_pos_traj_controller/type: position_controll...
 * /speed_scaling_state_controller/publish_rate: 125
 * /speed_scaling_state_controller/type: ur_controllers/Sp...
 * /ur_hardware_interface/headless_mode: False
 * /ur_hardware_interface/input_recipe_file: /root/underlay_ws...
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/pitch: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/roll: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/x: -0.425
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/y: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/yaw: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/z: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/hash: calib_20954911754...
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/pitch: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/roll: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/x: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/y: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/yaw: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/z: 0.089159
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/pitch: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/roll: 1.570796327
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/x: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/y: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/yaw: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/z: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/pitch: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/roll: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/x: -0.39225
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/y: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/yaw: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/z: 0.10915
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/pitch: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/roll: 1.570796327
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/x: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/y: -0.09465
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/yaw: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/z: -1.9413039509e-11
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/pitch: 3.14159265359
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/roll: 1.57079632659
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/x: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/y: 0.0823
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/yaw: 3.14159265359
 * /ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/z: -1.68800121668e-11
 * /ur_hardware_interface/output_recipe_file: /root/underlay_ws...
 * /ur_hardware_interface/reverse_port: 50003
 * /ur_hardware_interface/robot_ip: 192.168.0.42
 * /ur_hardware_interface/script_file: /root/underlay_ws...
 * /ur_hardware_interface/script_sender_port: 50004
 * /ur_hardware_interface/tf_prefix: 
 * /ur_hardware_interface/tool_baud_rate: 115200
 * /ur_hardware_interface/tool_parity: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/tool_rx_idle_chars: 1.5
 * /ur_hardware_interface/tool_stop_bits: 1
 * /ur_hardware_interface/tool_tx_idle_chars: 3.5
 * /ur_hardware_interface/tool_voltage: 0
 * /ur_hardware_interface/use_tool_communication: False

NODES
  /
    controller_stopper (controller_stopper/node)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    ros_control_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    ros_control_stopped_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    ur_hardware_interface (ur_robot_driver/ur_robot_driver_node)
  /ur_hardware_interface/
    ur_robot_state_helper (ur_robot_driver/robot_state_helper)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [27523]
process[ur_hardware_interface-2]: started with pid [27524]
[ INFO] [1585468473.264997939]: Initializing dashboard client
[ INFO] [1585468473.266447239]: Connected: Universal Robots Dashboard Server

[ INFO] [1585468473.272663237]: Initializing urdriver
[ INFO] [1585468473.272919634]: Checking if calibration data matches connected robot.
[ WARN] [1585468473.273107151]: No realtime capabilities found. Consider using a realtime system for better performance
[ERROR] [1585468473.481156794]: The calibration parameters of the connected robot don't match the ones from the given kinematics config file. Please be aware that this can lead to critical inaccuracies of tcp positions. Use the ur_calibration tool to extract the correct calibration from the robot and pass that into the description. See [TODO Link to documentation] for details.
process[ros_control_controller_spawner-3]: started with pid [27531]
[INFO] [1585468473.853100]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
process[ros_control_stopped_spawner-4]: started with pid [27541]
[INFO] [1585468474.230939]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[ WARN] [1585468474.286153653]: No realtime capabilities found. Consider using a realtime system for better performance
[ INFO] [1585468474.287541631]: Setting up RTDE communication with frequency 125.000000
process[controller_stopper-5]: started with pid [27555]
[ INFO] [1585468474.383239613]: Waiting for controller manager service to come up on /controller_manager/switch_controller
[ INFO] [1585468474.384151611]: waitForService: Service [/controller_manager/switch_controller] has not been advertised, waiting...
process[ur_hardware_interface/ur_robot_state_helper-6]: started with pid [27570]
[ WARN] [1585468475.322904728]: No realtime capabilities found. Consider using a realtime system for better performance
[ INFO] [1585468475.323065587]: Loaded ur_robot_driver hardware_interface
[INFO] [1585468475.360721]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1585468475.362305]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[ INFO] [1585468475.363155911]: waitForService: Service [/controller_manager/switch_controller] is now available.
[ INFO] [1585468475.363178449]: Service available.
[ INFO] [1585468475.363196928]: Waiting for controller list service to come up on /controller_manager/list_controllers
[INFO] [1585468475.363722]: Loading controller: joint_state_controller
[ INFO] [1585468475.363797109]: Service available.
[INFO] [1585468475.373545]: Loading controller: scaled_pos_traj_controller
[INFO] [1585468475.397388]: Loading controller: speed_scaling_state_controller
[INFO] [1585468475.405495]: Loading controller: force_torque_sensor_controller
[INFO] [1585468475.413467]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: joint_state_controller, scaled_pos_traj_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller
[FATAL] [1585468475.421218140]: Failed to start controller in realtime loop. This should never happen.
[INFO] [1585468475.421495]: Started controllers: joint_state_controller, scaled_pos_traj_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller
[INFO] [1585468475.437885]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1585468475.439328]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1585468475.440729]: Loading controller: pos_traj_controller
[INFO] [1585468475.445638]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: pos_traj_controller
[ INFO] [1585468475.541924290]: Robot's safety mode is now NORMAL
[ INFO] [1585468475.544218509]: Robot mode is now RUNNING
[ INFO] [1585468476.189390432]: Robot ready to receive control commands.
```

I followed the install instructions and made sure to install the dependencies with `rosdep` as explained [here](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/issues/55). I find few results on Google for this error message. There is [this thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/289021/unable-to-configure-custom-1dof-gripper-to-tiago-robot-arm/) that references the same error message, but it is not very helpful.

The error is confusing because I had the setup working before, but something must have changed. Any ideas to resolve this are appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347779/%22failed-to-start-controller-in-realtime-loop%22-with-ur/ure-robot-driver/) by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2180 on 2020-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dxp397@foxmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/52786/dxp397@foxmail.com/) on 2020-03-29**:
Hello there. I want to add an end effector to the UR, specifically to add a laser scanner. Do you know how to add it?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-29**:
Please post new questions separately via the "ASK YOUR QUESTION" button, not in a comment. Please also read the instructions carefully, since you seem to be mistaken about how the site is structured.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-29**:\

> I had the setup working before

The same setup? `ros_control` has quite a few changes between Kinetic and Melodic, hence my question.

That error message is from [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/a5a42f3586ffe70d04dc8d3b3ad880d86d01e8bb/controller_manager/src/controller_manager.cpp#L95-L112), which is interesting, as it's the Kinetic version of the `ControllerManager`. The Melodic version doesn't have it any more (since [ros-controls/ros_control#391](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/pull/391)). That PR was included in [0.16.0](https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_control-release#ros_control-melodic---0160-1), which was released on `Mon, 27 Jan 2020 14:30:01 GMT` and synced to the public repos on [5 Feb 2020 20:40:58 GMT](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-melodic-2020-02-05/12630).

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-29**:
It was running on Melodic before as well, yes. I also just checked that all controller-related packages point to `/opt/ros/share/melodic` and I can't find the error message in my workspaces either. How curious. I'll rebuild my docker image.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-29**:
What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep controller-manager`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-29**:\

> I'll rebuild my docker image.

Running the driver in a Docker container will likely interfere with the ability to run it with real-time priorities.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-30**:
Probably, but I won't depend on it. I just want the controllers to run at all. The output of that command after rebuilding the container is this:

```
ii  ros-melodic-controller-manager                     0.17.0-1bionic.20200320.133159     amd64        The controller manager.
ii  ros-melodic-controller-manager-msgs                0.17.0-1bionic.20200320.132558     amd64        Messages and services for the controller manager.
ii  ros-melodic-moveit-fake-controller-manager         1.0.2-1bionic.20200320.163635      amd64        A fake controller manager plugin for MoveIt.
ii  ros-melodic-moveit-simple-controller-manager       1.0.2-1bionic.20200320.161301      amd64        A generic, simple controller manager plugin for MoveIt.
```

However, I then got the errors reported in [this thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/343775/bringing-up-ur5-controller-spawner-shutted-down/). After a *full* rebuild, everything worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is unclear what the real issue was, but I assume that an installed package was outdated somehow. The error disappeared after reinstalling.

I assume updating the installed packages would have been enough: `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install ros-*`

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> After a full rebuild, everything worked.

I'm pretty sure your issue is a duplicate of #q343775 (ie: the ABI breakage).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-30**:
The underlying issue (an outdated package) and solution (update/rebuild) may be the same, but since the error message is different, I wouldn't consider it a duplicate. Thanks for carrying the link from the comments